# Find all Boxes containing files where all the files of the box have expiration date inferior to a DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

Title was complicated, here the request:
I want to select boxes (box).
All files (file) from a box need to have an expiration date inferior to '01/01/2022';
so does the box.

Here is a request not working, but giving the good JOIN :

```
select distinct b.code,b.EXPIRATION_DATE
from box b
join COMPONENT_A cpp on cpp.b_Id=b.Id
join COMPONENT_Z cpt on cpt.A_Id=cpp.Id
join file f on f.Z_Id =cpt.Id
where 
b.EXPIRATION_DATE < to_date('01.01.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
 and f.EXPIRATION_DATE < to_date('01.01.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

This request does not work because it still gives boxes where some files inside have EXPIRATION_DATE > to_date('01.01.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')

What I need Example :

Box_1(01/01/2001) : file1(01/01/1999); file2(01/01/2023) NOT SELECTED (because file 2)

Box_2(01/01/2024) : file1(01/01/1999); file2(01/01/2002) NOT SELECTED (box date)

Box_3(01/01/2001) : file1(01/01/1999); file2(01/01/2001) SELECTED (all < 01/01/2022)

I am sure there is a Group by somewhere, file table is a huge table so performance is important.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that is representative of the problem; the output from **YOUR** query for that sample data; the issues/errors with the output from **YOUR** query; and the expected output for that sample data. If you do not tell us what the starting data is or how the tables are related then we have to guess and you are unlikely to get an appropriate answer; so help us to help you by giving us a complete example in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that the maximum file date for each box code is less than 2022-01-01, you can use:

```sql
SELECT b.code,
       MAX(b.EXPIRATION_DATE) AS expiration_date
FROM   box b
       join COMPONENT_A cpp on cpp.b_Id=b.Id
       join COMPONENT_Z cpt on cpt.A_Id=cpp.Id
       join "FILE" f on f.Z_Id =cpt.Id
WHERE  b.EXPIRATION_DATE < DATE '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY b.code
HAVING MAX(f.EXPIRATION_DATE) < DATE '2022-01-01';
```

or, to invert the condition and check that there are no files in a box that are greater than or equal to 2022-01-01, you can use:

```sql
SELECT code,
       expiration_date
FROM   box b
WHERE  EXPIRATION_DATE < DATE '2022-01-01'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   COMPONENT_A cpp
                join COMPONENT_Z cpt on cpt.A_Id=cpp.Id
                join "FILE" f on f.Z_Id =cpt.Id
         WHERE  cpp.b_Id = b.Id
         AND    f.EXPIRATION_DATE >= DATE '2022-01-01'
       );
```

*(Note: there is a slight difference between the two queries when a box has no files. The first query will not return a box with no files whereas the second query would.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE box (id, code, expiration_date) AS
SELECT 1, 'Box_1', DATE '2001-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Box_2', DATE '2024-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Box_3', DATE '2001-01-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE component_a (id, b_id) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE component_z (id, a_id) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE "FILE" (id, z_id, expiration_date) AS
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '1999-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, DATE '1999-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, DATE '2002-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3, DATE '1999-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 3, DATE '2001-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | CODE | EXPIRATION_DATE |
> | --- | --- |
> | Box_3 | 01-JAN-01 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=91029e51e8b5e39b865225e1de807037)*

Comment: It takes only the boxes where all files (without filter) have expiration_date < DATE '2022-01-01'  ?

Comment: @Benoît The first query checks that the maximum file date is less than 2022-01-01 (and by implication all the other files' dates must be less than or equal to that date). The second query checks that there are no files with an expiration date greater than or equal to 2022-01-01 (and by implication there must either be no files or all files' dates are less than that date).

Comment: @Benoît It works fine in the linked db<>fiddle. I can't help you if you just give an error message as I cannot tell what you have changed. I suggest that you go through the code and look at the differences between whatever code you have used and the code in my answer and make sure that they correspond and fix any differences.

Comment: Some files have NO Date, If so, the box should not be selected. How to exclude the boxes where at least ONE file has NO Date (null or empty) ? @MT0

Comment: @Benoît You should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide a [MRE] rather than coming back to an old one several months later and trying to expand its scope.

Comment: I have done it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950611/avoir-some-null-and-empty-values-in-a-group-by

Answer (score 0):

If `expiration_date` columns' datatype is `DATE`, then don't compare them to strings. Use date literal or `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format mask. Both options below:

```
where b.EXPIRATION_DATE < date '2022-01-01'
  and f.EXPIRATION_DATE < to_date('01.01.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

---

As of the query itself, you didn't post sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements; it is difficult for us to guess what might be written in those 4 tables) so I created my own, simplified test case.

I *removed* `component%` tables, but - what might be useful here - is the `temp` CTE which returns `max` `expiration_date` for each box - then you'd use it in the final query.

Something like this:

```
SQL> with box (code, expiration_date) as
  2    (select 'Box_1', date '2001-01-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'Box_3', date '2001-01-01' from dual
  4    ),
  5  tfile (code, cfile, expiration_date) as
  6    (select 'Box_1', 'file1', date '1999-01-01' from dual union all
  7     select 'Box_1', 'file2', date '2023-01-01' from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select 'Box_3', 'file1', date '1999-01-01' from dual union all
 10     select 'Box_3', 'file2', date '2001-01-01' from dual
 11    ),
 12  --
 13  temp as
 14    -- find MAX expiration_date for each box code
 15    (select code, max(expiration_date) expiration_date
 16     from tfile
 17     group by code
 18    )
 19  select b.code, b.expiration_date
 20  from box b join temp f on f.code = b.code
 21  where b.expiration_date < date '2022-01-01'
 22    and f.expiration_date < date '2022-01-01';

CODE  EXPIRATION
----- ----------
Box_3 01.01.2001

SQL>
```

Comment: That's not just the "tip". It causes a lot of problems for many developers. As of the rest of your question, I tried to *simulate* what you're doing. Have a look, please.

Comment: I did not constructed the database, and the date are strings :/  Thanks for the answer I'll try this!

Comment: Your example doesn't work : I don't have the BoxCode in the "file" table.

Comment: I know you don't have it - it requires additional joins with two additional tables I didn't specify. If **you** posted proper test case, it would be easier for us to write queries against them. Until then, feel free to add them to sample query I posted and see what happens.